# Uncaught TypeError is not a function on AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

In my `application.js` file, I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place */
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();

  $('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){$(this).closest('div.social-comment').effect('highlight');});
});
```

I am using the [Best In Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#binding-to-ajaxsuccess) gem, and it gives me the above function to use in my `best_in_place` call.

However, when I use it, I get this error in my JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).effect is not a function application.self-440dd817e40548768e9.js:25
```

How do I fix this and get it work?

Comment: `effect()` is probably from jQueryUI . Is it included in page?

Comment: Ahh ok. No....I am not using jQueryUI. What's an alternative I can use for vanilla jQuery to get a similar effect?

Comment: Only if you write it as a jQuery plugin named `effect()` since it is being called from within `best_in_place` I assume

Comment: You could create a CSS transition with a similar effect, and then just add the appropriate class.

Comment: @Barmar but either have to modify the original plugin to remove `effect()` call or write a `noop` plugin with the same name along with doing it in css

Comment: Ahh ok. The simplest thing it seems is just to use jQueryUI. If you convert the above comments into a complete answer, I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: Shame to add that whole library just for one tiny feature. You can create a custom build but will still be overkill

Comment: Well the beautiful thing is with the `jquery-ui-rails` gem, I can just add that one `effect` module, as opposed to the entire UI library (which is what I was trying to avoid). So it works out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`effect()` is part of jQueryUI not jQuery core so either need to find a different editing script that doesn't have dependencies other than some css or use jQueryUI also in page to include that function.

Personally I would look for a different editor like X-ediable or other simlar plugin